# The header function is not working on online server?

Tags: php, php-5.3

hi i just dont understand why my code is not working. i am using yahoo server for my site.

This is my logout code.(which is successfully run on localhost) but when i upload this code online then its not work. plz help

```
<?php  
//logout code

include("../Config.php");
if (!isset ($_SESSION['username']))
    {
header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
header('Location: ../index.php');

if (!headers_sent())
  { 
  header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php');
  exit;
  }
    }
    else
    {

$_SESSION = array();
session_destroy();
session_unset();
header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' ); 
header('Location: ../index.php');

if (!headers_sent())
  { 
  header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php');
  exit;
  }
}

?>
```

the config.php file includes session code (like start session)

Comment: Is there any error page returns? Could you check this with display_errors=on

Comment: @Asif Mulla did you know what is the actual problem

Comment: What is this code supposed to do? What does it do instead?

Comment: @Pekka it is a user logout code.

Comment: the logout run successfully but the header function is not working . it do not redirect the page to main page(index.php)

Comment: @Pratik why are you sending headers twice? What reasoning is behind that?

Comment: @Pekka i am just testing but no result

Comment: but this code run on my pc|(localhost)

Comment: May be header already sent issue. Could you please check this http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#76375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the full URI in the header, and I recommend to use exit() right after the location header. There is no need for the 301 header for a simple log out.
And [don't use the closing tag in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219383/why-in-some-scripts-they-omit-the-closing-php-tag). If it is working on your system, it looks, there is some output (maybe just an empty line) in at least one of your php files (before the starting php tag, or after the closing php tag), and it seems that output buffering is enabled in your PHP, which work around this error, but disabled on the production server.

Try this:

```
<?php
// for debugging purposes only, don't use on production server (just for debugging)
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

//logout code

include("../Config.php");

if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
    session_destroy();

header('Location: http://www.mysite.com/index.php');
exit;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    function delayer(){
     window.location = "../index.php"
 }
 setTimeout("delayer()", 1000);

   </script>';
```

You could put this instead of header

Comment: simply this code will work: `echo '<script type="text/javascript">window.location = "../index.php"</script>'`

Answer (score 0):

This will work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.location="http://www.newlocation.com"; 
</script>
```