# php redirect() not working on online server

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I had redirected my page like:

```
redirect(base_url().'user/login/?redirect=site/cart_steps/steps');
```

and it works fine in localhost and when i uploaded it to server it didnt redirect. I checked all the codes and above this all code executes. But when it comes to redirect the page doesnt redirects. I also tried

```
redirect(base_url().'user/login?redirect=site/cart_steps/steps');
redirect(base_url().'user/login');
header('Location:'.base_url().'user/login?redirect=site/cart_steps/steps');
header('Location:'.base_url().'user/login');
```

but the page didn't redirect? and also i checked out this [The header function is not working on online server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183075/the-header-function-is-not-working-on-online-server)
but it cant help me too.... can any one explain what is the problem here....

Comment: check for base_url() what it contains and is it containing your server path ?

Comment: ya it does...i checked it out..and it is correct

Comment: When redirecting with header(), you must be sure nothing is output the browser prior to the redirect.  See the php manual for further notes:  http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

As for `redirect()`... is that a function you defined?  There's no php function named redirect() I've heard of, or according to the manual.

Comment: redirect() is from the code igniter default library...

Comment: Sounds like something in the webserver configuration is filtering out headers sent by the scripts.

Comment: If you do `echo base_url().'user/login?redirect=site/cart_steps/steps';` does the URL look correct?

Comment: ya the url is correct...i did ?redirect=... to redirect the page user/login to ../site/cart_steps/steps after the login is success

Comment: Check that you do a exit or die just after your header function and check that you do no echo anything before (if something is echo, the header will not work).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the refresh method like this:

```
    <?php
        redirect($this->input->server('HTTP_REFERER'), 'refresh'); // refresh the page
    ?>
```

Another common mistake could be echoing out / printing something before the redirection.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your CodeIgniter error logs to verify that particular file isn't throwing any error messages that could tell you what needs fixing.

If you haven't already, you'll probably also want to make sure that the URL helper is loaded.
ex:

```
$this->load->helper('url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" url=http://example.com/">
```

Comment: then may be problem with your web server config file..and no output before these function load->helper, loader, header or any .

Answer (score 0):

Try to use like this,

First define your base URL as :

```
$base_url = "Your base url";
```

then apply this $base_url variable to your redirect link.

Hope this will help.