# Error while executing php script from bash

Tags: php, bash

Hi im trying to execute php file from bash script

```
#!/bin/sh

php ./func.php
```

and `func.php` file looks like

```
<?php

echo "php file";
```

And as output
`PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0`

EDIT:
And maybe U can also tell me how to pass parameter to php file ??

Comment: Have you tried checking the cli configuration file (on a Ubuntu system it would e.g. be located in `/etc/php5/cli/php.ini`) for references to module `apc`? And is this your complete `func.php` file? Looks incomplete to me (at least closing `?>` is missing)

Comment: @nyarlathotep Leaving out the closing `?>` [is a best practice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4453835/35070).

Comment: @phihag: thanks for the hint! been writing php code for a long time but didn't know that - seems I should read up on best practices :)

Comment: I thought that `?>` its not so important as it is in PHP. Thanks

Comment: @skowron-line Please ask a second question on how to get parameters. That way, this question remains uncluttered, and future seekers will have an easier time reading questions and answers.

Comment: unrelated to your error but you must use `#!/bin/bash` if you really want bash, otherwise your script will run in compatibility mode (POSIX)

Answer (score 8):

An error in `Unknown on line 0` means that your configuration is defective (this has nothing to do with bash - directly running the program should yield the same message).

In your case, you have two instances of `extension=apc.so` in your php configuration. Use 
`grep apc.so /etc/php5/cli/ -r` to find these.

Comment: Thanks +1 ! Do you have any idea where this duplicate line comes from ? I also had an ...active=1 line duplicated in the ini file.

Answer (score 3):

This error is related to your PHP configuration, not to your code.

This can be fixed in your `php.ini`, check this thread: http://blog.ciuly.com/my-server/php-warning-module-apc-already-loaded-in-unknown-on-line-0/.

Answer (score 2):

Find out which `php.ini`  is being used in CLI mode:

```
php --info
```

and check the content of that `php.ini` for a double declaration of `extension=apc.so`

Answer (score 1):

All of the answers above hinted at what was going on, but it was the fact that there was a separate apc file that was being loaded, so simply grepping for "extension=apc.so" didn't uncover the issue.

```
php --info | grep -i apc
PHP Warning:  Module 'apc' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php5/cli/conf.d/apc.ini
```

So since the module was being loaded, you just simply need to remove the "extension=apc.so" from both your apache and cli php.ini configs.

Answer (score 0):

In my case (on Ubuntu, a Debian based Linux variant), I had two copies of `apc.ini` in `/etc/php5/conf.d/`.   I had one that I had put there when I first installed apc.  I also found a symlink from `/etc/php5/conf.d/20-apc.ini` to `../mods-available/apc.ini`.

It appears that some upgrade of php, enabled this module the "Debian way" (with a symlink). I deleted my copy of apc.ini and I am now just using the one that is symlinked to `mods-available`.

Digging further, there are command line programs that should be used to enable and disable PHP modules under Ubuntu and Debian.  Here are the commands to enable and disable APC:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/php5enmod apc # Creates the symlink in /etc/php5/conf.d that enables APC
sudo /usr/sbin/php5dismod apc # Deletes the symlink in /etc/php5/conf.d that disables APC
```