# cakephp 3 [RuntimeException] Unable to configure the session, setting session.cookie_path failed

Tags: php, session, cakephp, cookies

I try to transfer a cakephp3 application from my local server to a webspace.

I get the following error-message:

> [RuntimeException] Unable to configure the session, setting session.cookie_path failed

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

http://marcusmoenius.lima-city.de/app/users/login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I applied a workaround:

following the stacktrace I opened the file

> /app/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Session.php(212): Cake\Network\Session->options(Array)

and scrolled to line 212

there I changed

```
    if (!empty($config['ini']) && is_array($config['ini'])) {
        $this->options($config['ini']);
    }
```

to

```
    if (!empty($config['ini']) && is_array($config['ini'])) {
        //$this->options($config['ini']);
    }
```

My website loads now and I can login and logout

Answer (score 0):

Cake is using ini_set to modify that setting as far as i know.
Either the webhoster providing your webspace prohibits setting cookie_path or prohibits using ini_set completly.

Btw: http://marcusmoenius.lima-city.de/ shows output of phpinfo from your server. Thats a security risk, you should disable it.

Edit: Using google may have solved you problem faster: [CakePHP Error: Unable to configure the session, setting session.auto_start failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004460/cakephp-session-error)