# PHP header not redirecting, but there is no output in front of it

Tags: php, mysql, forms, redirect, header

I have a php page that allows the user to input some data, and tries to put them into a database. However, my header is not working. It runs the query, but stops at the header, and displays a blank page. Can someone help me out?

```
<?php   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $user_vcode = $_POST['user_vcode'];
    $send_data = true;

    if(empty($user_id) || empty($user_vcode)){
        $send_data = false;
    }

    if($send_data){
        require("../../db.php");
        $account_id = $_COOKIE['account_id'];
        $query = "INSERT INTO api (key_id, key_vcode, owner_id) VALUES ('$user_id', '$user_vcode', '$account_id')";
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query) or die("Failed querying database");
        mysqli_close($dbc);
        header("Location: http://www.google.com");
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Does `../../db.php` have any trailing whitespace? Do you have `E_ALL` set for error reporting?

Comment: Ah okay. I was the error once again. This fixed everything. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace at the end of the file can be a big pain.  Check for any trailing carriage returns or spaces after the final `?>` tag.

Comment: I usually leave off the closing ?> for this reason.

Comment: With all due respect Brent, that's a bit of a lazy practice.  See this long running debate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/php-closing-tag

Comment: The problem was the require(). It had a full html document, instead of just php.