# How to avoid empty lines while downloading/exporting csv file in laravel 4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, export-to-csv

Hi i am developing an application using laravel 4 and when i try to download my report in csv format it inserts 4 new empty line before header and i want to get rid of those empty lines.

Here is my code

```
public function getDownloadCsv()
    {

        // Grab all the assets
        $assettypes = Assettype::orderBy('id', 'ASC')->select('id', 'asset_type')->get();


        $rows = array();

        // Asset Type Id
        $header = array(
            Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/table.assetnum'),
            Lang::get('admin/assetdetails/table.asset_name'),

        );
        $header = array_map('trim', $header);
        $rows[] = implode($header,',');

        // Create a row per asset
        foreach ($assettypes as $assettype) {
            $row = array();
            $row[] = $assettype->id;
            $row[] = $assettype->asset_type;
            $rows[] = implode($row,',');
        }

          // spit out a csv
         $csv = implode($rows,("\n"));
         $response = Response::make($csv, 200);
         $response->header('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
         $response->header('Content-disposition', 'attachment;filename=Help_document_for_asset_import.csv');
         return $response;
        }
```

If you need any further details please let me know.
Please help me to achieve this....

Comment: Empty lines are always a pain in the neck. Check this one first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728791/laravel-displays-an-empty-line-before-the-doctype

Comment: @Adrenaxus yes i saw that but i dont have any php tag in my code.

Comment: @Adrenaxus thanks.I checked all the files and in one of the file i had empty lines and i removed that space,now its working fine. Thanks for your valuable answer.

Comment: You're welcome. Please answer your own question and mark is at accepted for future reference. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i solved the issue, thanks to Adrenaxus valuable comments all i did is deleted all the empty lines after closing php tag.Please note that you must do this in all php files in your application.

In my case i checked the current file which i was working and failed to replace the empty lines in other php files but the issue was still happening,removing empty spaces in all php files did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I did solve this problem by using function [ob_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-clean.php), You may also need to use [ob_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) OR [ob_end_clean()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) depending on your code.