# How to solve datatable 403 forbidden in production Laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have some code to request datatable via jquery ajax that returns:

> 403 forbidden

in a production environment, it's working properly in my local environment.

[image: Error snap]

When I open url directly in browser it shows JSON array.

[image: JSON array snap]

this is my ajax request:

```
$(function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        var state = true;
        var otable = $('#example').DataTable({
            processing: true,
            serverSide: true,
            ajax: "{{ route('get.data') }}",
            columns: [
                { data: 'CountryCode', name: 'CountryCode' },
                { data: 'CountryName', name: 'CountryName' },
                { data: 'FgActive', name: 'FgActive' },
                { data: 'action', name: 'action' }
            ]
        });
```

my route

```
Route::get('get-data-my-datatables', [
    'as'=>'get.data',
    'uses'=>'CountryController@getData'
]);
```

Below is function in controller

```
public function getData()
{
    $country = Country::all();

    return datatables()
       ->of($country)
       ->addColumn('action', function ($country) {
           return 
               '<button type="button" name="'.$country->CountryCode.'" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-pencil" id="btnEdit" data-toggle="modal"></button>
               <button type="button" name="'.$country->CountryCode.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm fa fa-trash" id="btnDel" data-toggle="modal"></button>'
           ;

    })
    ->make(true);
}
```

Thank you for your attention.

---

## Update

As requested, this is my network tab:

[image: snap network tab]

Comment: Add a snap of Network tab

Comment: Is there correct `CSRF`-token sent?

Comment: @Ruchi please check network tab

Comment: @Grabatui please check ajax setup

Comment: No, not `General` block. Show `Request Headers`

Comment: @Grabatui request headers :http://prntscr.com/p1inre

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272557/laravel-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server

Comment: What middlewares are you applying to this route? Does it have the web middleware attached?

Comment: You are GETing the data. Shouldn't you POST? Both in Ajax and the Route.

Comment: @DelightedD0D I cannot using middleware route.. any example

Comment: @DimitriMostrey I just followed documentation

Comment: @trapdoor00 what happens if you add `, 'middleware'=>['web']` to the second param for your `Route::get`? Like `Route::get('get-data-my-datatables', [
            'as'=>'get.data',
            'uses'=>'CountryController@getData', 
            'middleware'=>['web']
        ]);`

Comment: @DelightedD0D ok i will try

Comment: @DelightedD0D just same 403 forbidden

Comment: Maybe check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40050335/laravelangular-projects-auth-and-csrf-token-not-working-in-production?rq=1), or [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/698004/laravel-5-csrf-on-prod-server-not-dev) some issue with sessions not storing properly is about the only other thing I can think of

Comment: @DelightedD0D problem solved reference https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/40445/unable-to-add-additional-columns-due-to-ajax-error just change from ajax to "sAjaxSource" https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#sAjaxSource