# Int or not Int. How to fix the code?

Tags: php, string, int

I would like the code below to return 'Int' the first time and 'Not int' the second time. Unfortunately it returns 'Not int' twice instead.

How can I fix this?

```
<?php
$test1='1';
if(is_int($test1)){
        echo "Int";
}else{
        echo "Not int";
}

echo "\n";

$test2='1a';
if(is_int($test2)){
        echo "Int";
}else{
        echo "Not int";
}
?>
```

Comment: `'1'` is a string, not an int.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By wrapping the number in quotation marks `'1'`, you are declaring a string.
Instead you got to use `$test1 = 1;`.

By using the PHP [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) function, you can check if a string only contains digits.
You could also use the [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) function, which also returns true if the string contains a exponential part like `+0123.45e6` or a hex value `0xFF`.

Answer (score 2):

is_int - Find whether the type of a variable is integer
Because you put the number in quotes, it is a string. Therefore is_int = false

is_numeric — Finds whether a variable is a number or a numeric string
Because the string is actually a number, is_numeric will return true

So, change is_int to is_numeric and it works:

```
<?php
$test1 = '1';
if (is_numeric($test1))
{
    echo 'Int';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not int';
}

echo "\n";

$test2 = '1a';
if (is_numeric($test2))
{
    echo 'Int';
}
else
{
    echo 'Not int';
}
?>
```

Comment: It might be a good idea to provide explanation of difference between `is_int` and `is_numeric`.

Comment: is_numeric will be proven true if 1e4 or 909.89 are given.

Comment: It is also a good idea to omit the closing tag (`?>`) at the end of code, as [mentioned by the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) and [outlined at StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4499749/548696).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`ctype_digit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-digit.php) instead.

```
ctype_digit('1'); // True
ctype_digit('1a'); // False
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
 $test1='1';
```

to

```
 $test1=1;
```