# Include a php file with a lot of includes using ajax .load()

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, include

I'm trying to load an php file through ajax using load(). Here's my code:

```
var loadUrl = "myfile.php";                             
$("#lst-results").load(loadUrl);
```

So, when I do this, it works:

```
<?php   
$test = 'Hi :3';    
?>
<h3>Hi</h3>
<h3><?php echo $test ?></h3>
```

But I need to include a file that contain a lot of includes and functions using a lot of different classes. I've tryed to include this file and use it as a function like this, but does not work and Nothing appears int the load() results. This function return an array.

```
<?php
include 'path/myfile.php';
$result = myFunction(); 
?>
```

I can't figure out how to solve it. :(

Comment: Avoid PHP end tags (unrelatedly) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/php-closing-tag

Comment: What does your `myFunction` output? What do you see in your load() results?

Comment: My function returns an array.

When I do this:
<?php
include 'path/myfile.php';
$result = myFunction(); 
?>

Nothing appears int the  load() results

Answer (score 0):

You need to "echo" the $result.

```
<?php
    include 'path/myfile.php';
    $result = myFunction();
    echo $result;
```

Comment: If the function returns array, it won't work. You need to return HTML markup in some form. Can you post the myFunction() script?

Comment: Just one question to you: `Do you want to invoke php functions via JavaScript?`