# How to enable PHP session without config other files

Tags: php, html

I include this code on top of my php webpage

```
<?php
ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);
ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
session_start();
?>
```

here is php webpage
**a.php**

```
<h1>Page AAAA</h1>
<a href="b.php?t=<? echo time(); ?>">go to page B</a>
<?php
   echo "<h2>CURRENT SESSION = ", $_SESSION['test'], "</h2>";
   $_SESSION['test'] = 'a';
   echo "<h2>AFTER CHANGE SESSION = ", $_SESSION['test'], "</h2>";
?>
```

**b.php**

```
<h1>Page BBBB</h1>
<a href="a.php?t=<? echo time(); ?>">go to page A</a>
<?php
   echo "<h2>CURRENT SESSION = ", $_SESSION['test'], "</h2>";
   $_SESSION['test'] = 'b';
   echo "<h2>AFTER CHANGE SESSION = ", $_SESSION['test'], "</h2>";
?>
```

but it not work. `CURRENT SESSION` is no value even if I switch between **a.php** and **b.php**

**update** I include this code in **a.php** 
 `echo "<h1>SESSION ID = ", session_id() , "</h1>";` 

result 
  `SESSION ID = fhhiilg08rl2ajtplqc9dbud43`

Comment: Try`!session_id() ? session_start() : null` and set error reporting on to see what error is occurring

Comment: What does "on top of my php webpage" mean? Are you starting the session in a.php and b.php? Try activating error reporting if you haven't already.

Comment: [**Read this**](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp)

Comment: I recommend remove `?>` in the included PHP snippet. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/php-closing-tag

Comment: I mean copy that code and place on top of php webpage files before html tag start

Comment: @hsgu you have write session_start() at the beginning of both the pages i.e a.php and b.php and on every single page where youi want to use session

Comment: I want output CURRENT SESSION = a after I click go to page B from page A but now result on my server side CURRENT SESSION = NOTHING

Comment: @hsgu have you written session_start() on both the a.php & b.php pages?

Comment: I have certainly write session_start(); in both page. It's very depress to get down vote because I can't find the cause of my strange result. Am I ask the stupid question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your  php.ini file and set

```
session.use_cookies=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
```

So by setting this you will not require config other files

And just start session on pages where you want to assess session variables by

```
session_start()
```

Comment: Now I edit php.ini session.use_cookies=1 already and I let session.use_only_cookies=1 out of comment but session still not work correctly.

Comment: @hsgu I tried your code on my system I got answer as 
Page BBBB
go to page A
CURRENT SESSION = a

Page AAAA
go to page B
CURRENT SESSION = b
AFTER CHANGE SESSION = a
AFTER CHANGE SESSION = b
when I clicked on go to page a link I got output as

Comment: Thank so much. I try it with my friend as well my server got nothing on CURRENT SESSION but my friend got it fine what should I do at this point.

Comment: @hsgu  try by restarting your webserver!

Comment: WOWWWWWW!!!! I restart webserver and it's work fine thank!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use `session_start();` function on top of the page then assign value to `$_SESSION['test'] = "value"`. This show session value on all the pages.