# Magento export products, categories from database dump

Tags: mysql, magento, export

I have to migrate magento to new custom made webshop engine. But I only have mysql dump from magento 1.6.0.0 (core_resource admin_setup version value. The original magento isn't available! )

I would like to export all of product (pictures or the path of the picture, attributes etc.), categories and if possible the orders to CSV / XML or anything else.

Which is the fastest working way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Option 1: Install a Dev version of Magento

Your best bet would be to install Mage 1.6.0.0, then restore the DB there. Then you can use the already established tools to run an export. If you're experienced with Magento, this shouldn't take you more than an hour or two.

Here's two good articles on running it that way. This is the preferred method, as some of the relations are maintained in the Magento Core.

- [Minimize database in order to export all products from Magento](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14244436/minimize-database-in-order-to-export-all-products-from-magento)
- [How to Export Your Magento Product Database](http://lero9.co.nz/magento-tips/how-to-export-your-magento-product-database-using-using-magentos-importexport-dataflow-profiles/)

### Option 2: If the above is not an option, or you are not familiar enough with Magento to install it:

- [MySQL only catalog export of Magento](http://www.michelem.org/2012/06/18/magento-how-to-create-a-super-fast-catalog-export-for-google-merchant/)

This is a short snippet by [Michele Marcucci](http://www.michelem.org/), which is designed for creating a CSV export for Google Merchant.

```
define('SAVE_FEED_LOCATION','google_feed.csv');
set_time_limit(0);
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask( 0 );
Mage::app( "default" );

Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

try {
$handle = fopen(SAVE_FEED_LOCATION, 'w');
$heading = array('id','mpn','ean','title','google_product_category','description','link','image_link','price','brand','product_type','condition', 'availability');
$feed_line= implode("\t", $heading)."\r\n";
fwrite($handle, $feed_line);

$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');

$readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');

$query = "SELECT * FROM catalog_product_flat_1 WHERE visibility=4 AND type_id='{$type}'";

$tax = "1.21"; // Insert your tax product
$currency = "EUR";

$products = $readConnection->fetchAll($query);

foreach($products as $product) {
$product_data = array();
$product_data['sku'] = $product['sku'];
$product_data['mpn'] = $product['sku'];
$product_data['ean'] = $product['sku'];
$product_data['title'] = ucfirst(strtolower($product['name']));
$product_data['google_product_category'] = 'INSERT YOUR DEFAULT CATEGORY';

if ($product['description'] != "")
$product_data['description'] = Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate(str_replace('“', '"', str_replace('”', '"', iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE", strip_tags($product['description'])))), 8000); // removes most the utf8 errors (doesnt like row if empty too!)
else
$product_data['description'] = "Description not available";

$product_data['deeplink'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).$product['url_path']; // thanks to hamish for this
$product_data['image_link'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product['small_image'];

if($product['special_price'] != NULL){ // update to check for special price or discount
$product_data['price'] = number_format(($product['special_price']*$tax), 2, ",", "") . " $currency";
} else {
$product_data['price'] = number_format(($product['price']*$tax), 2, ",", "") . " $currency";
}

$product_data['brand'] = "INSERT YOUR BRAND";
$product_data['product_type'] = "";
$product_data['condition'] = "new";
$product_data['availability'] = "in stock";

$i = 1;

$queryCats = "SELECT name FROM catalog_category_product JOIN catalog_category_flat_store_1 ON catalog_category_product.category_id = catalog_category_flat_store_1.entity_id WHERE product_id={$product['entity_id']}";

$cats = $readConnection->fetchAll($queryCats);
$numCat = count($cats);
foreach($cats as $_category){
if ($i == $numCat)
$product_data['product_type'] .= $_category['name'];
else
$product_data['product_type'] .= $_category['name'] . " > ";
$i++;
}

foreach($product_data as $k=>$val){
$bad=array('"',"\r\n","\n","\r","\t");
$good=array(""," "," "," ","");
$product_data[$k] = '"'.str_replace($bad,$good,$val).'"';
}

$feed_line = implode("\t", $product_data)."\r\n";
fwrite($handle, $feed_line);
fflush($handle);

}

fclose($handle);

}
catch(Exception $e)
{
die($e->getMessage());
}
```