# PHP spits a new line before any output

Tags: php, apache

I have a VPS from 1&1 with CentOS 5.2 64-bit.

Last Tuesday I've upgraded PHP and installed ImageMagick which had to upgrade many other packages, including Apache, MySQL, Perl, etc. Lots of stuff got upgraded in the process but being a complete noob I just went with it.

Now the problem is that all the websites look like this:

```
1.
﻿2. <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/    xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

(a new line on every single PHP file before output)

I even tried `ob_start();` and `die(trim(ob_get_clean()));` with no luck. The new line continues to persist.

I briefly checked `/etc/php.ini` with nothing standing out.

What can I do?

Comment: And what does one of your PHP pages look like?

Comment: It doesn't do this locally. Worked very well before the upgrade. It's not BOM, I just tried `header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` nothing good. The problem is still here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shot in the dark, but check your php.ini for an `auto-prepend-file` value. It might be pointing to a blank default file which happens to have a line break.

Comment: Just checked `/etc/php.ini`, I have `; auto_append_file = ` and `; auto_prepend_file = ` both commented out. :(

Comment: +1 for those ini directives, I had forgotten those tricky guys were in there. I could also see some sneaky plugin/upgrade using it to make their code 'globablly' available.

Comment: `pear list: Archive_Tar, Console_Getopt, Mail, PEAR, Structures_Graph, XML_RPC; pecl list: imagick.` compacted for convenience.

Comment: After a major struggle I discovered that the `php.ini` had an extra `[COM] auto_prepend_file=/tmp/.tmp.err` which contain the God-damn new line. commented that out and everything is fine!!!!!! whew!

Comment: HAH! The shot in the dark strikes again! :) Glad I could help man, cheers!

Answer (score 3):

The most probable cause of this is some base include file having whitespace at the end of it. If any include file has any characters outsite of the `<?php` and `?>` tags, including line breaks or spaces, then apache will write a blank line to the beginning of the response, like you're seeing.

Unfortunately, any file in your include chain could be the culprit. If you're on a shared hosting provider, then you may need to contact their support to ensure they don't have any wacky php auto-include behavior or apache directives, like AlienWebguy mentions. Here's a good Stack Overflow question about [best practices for include files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag). (It even points out that Smarty, a 3rd party php templating plugin had spare whitespace in its include files, even in recent/current releases.)

And here's a likely looking article for how to [find and kill pages with whitespace on them.](http://jimbojw.com/wiki/index.php?title=How_to_find_PHP_files_with_trailing_whitespace) If your *nix-fu is strong enough, you could grep your file structure with a regex to try and find any such culprit. Preventatively, Mario in the SO question linked posts a few php directives which can warn about it, which could be thrown into an svn commit hook to catch any such future errors.

Comment: It seems to have only happened since his upgrade though.

Comment: And the culprit could be in any one of the new files that got installed or modified.

Comment: I have SVN on the server, but none of my PHPs end in `?>`. I just installed ruby and ran that command to confirm. (only some admin areas had) I'm not on shared hosting, it's a VPS.