# PHPExcel return a corrupted binary file

Tags: php, file, phpexcel, xls

I want to write a reference xls file and retrieve the result.
When I tested with a single file, it works but when the reference file is complex, this returns me a corrupt file with with kinds of data:
[image]

[image]
Which is at the beginning like this:
[image]

My php file is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

if (PHP_SAPI == 'cli')
    die('This example should only be run from a Web Browser');

/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once '../phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('../upload/ref/fileref.xls');

$objWorksheet = $objPHPexcel->getActiveSheet();

$objWorksheet = $objPHPexcel->getActiveSheet();
$objWorksheet->getCell('B1')->setValue('toto');
$objWorksheet->getCell('B3')->setValue('toto');







header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="newfiletodownload.xls"');;
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate');
header ('Pragma: public');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Do you have solution ?
Thanks, Neyoh

Comment: Open the file in a text editor: look for leading/trailing whitespace characters, BOM header at the top of the file, or any plaintext messages.... then look for where your script is echoing/printing anything, or has anything (newlines, etc) outside of PHP `<?php` and `?>` tags

Comment: Double check that you have nothing (not even a new line) after the closing `?>` that I see in the code you've posted.... none of the PHPExcel examples or scripts have a terminating `?>` for precisely this reason.... though what is the `}` that I also see supposed to be closing? You have no opening `{`, so you could also be getting a basic PHP error message

Comment: I checked, this isn't } or ?> the problem. I update the post with other image

Comment: Try writing xls to a file on disk, not `php://output` and check if it is still corrupted. If still corrupted then try `$objPHPexcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('../upload/ref/fileref.xls'); $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPexcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('/path/to/file.xls');` and check if opening and saving a file without modifications also corrupt file. If so then try updating phpexcel library if newer is available. If you have most recent version send a bug report to phpexcel team with your excel file attached and code you use.

Comment: @piotrekkr - Thanks for suggesting sending the file as well: it's amazing how many people believe that a problem can be diagnosed without any of that critical data

Comment: Oh piotrekkr, i just tried with save on disk it's work :) But i need to download this directly.

Comment: But almost inevitably, this indicates that something in the script is injecting additional output somewhere into the php://output stream, typically at the beginning or the end.... and opening the file in a text editor will generally confirm this.... an [ob_end_clean()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-end-clean.php) immediately before the save() will normally resolve this, but it is a workround rather than a solution to the problem

Comment: Yes Mark, with ob_end_clean at the end, It seems to work, perfect. Thank you so much Mark Baker and piotrekkr.

Comment: Can you try to put ```ob_end_clean();``` just before the ```header(...)``` part?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Can you try to put `ob_end_clean();` just before the `header(...)` part?

This worked for someone with the same problem. See the comment at the accepted answer of this post: [PHPExcel generated excel file not working. (File format or extension is invalid )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805851/phpexcel-generated-excel-file-not-working-file-format-or-extension-is-invalid).

**Note**:

Using `ob_end_clean()` is just a work around for this problem. The main problem is that additional and unnecessary outputs are sent to the `PHPExcelWriter` that causes the file to get messed up.

Comment: Yes that's probably the good solution too. Mark Baker has said the same. Look the discution into my post. But thanks