# Excel file generated but it does not display the text proper. It display text in encrypeted form

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

When i m generating excel file from my codeigniter code it does not display the text proper. It display the text in encrypted form. 
Please Help me:
My code is like:

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
    ->setCellValue('A1', 'Id')
    ->setCellValue('B1', 'Name')
    ->setCellValue('C1', 'Email')
    ->setCellValue('D1', 'Number')
    ->setCellValue('E1', 'Message');

$filename='report.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"'); //tell browser what's the file name
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0'); //no cache

//save it to Excel5 format (excel 2003 .XLS file), change this to 'Excel2007' (and adjust the filename extension, also the header mime type)
//if you want to save it as .XLSX Excel 2007 format
//$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($this->excel, 'Excel5');  
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "in encrypted form": Do you mean like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131751/phpexcel-return-a-corrupted-binary-file)?

Comment: It Displays the data in excel like this:PKðvsFG’D²Xð[Content_Types].xml­”MNÃ0…÷œ"ò%nY „švAa •(0ö¤±êØ–gúw{&i‰@ÕnbEö{ßøyìÑdÛ¸l   
 mð¥‘×ÁX¿(ÅÛü)¿’òF¹à¡;@1_æ»˜±Øc)j¢x/%ê…Eˆày¦

Comment: Then read the comments in that post, and look for anywhere in your script that is generating output (including whitespace)

Comment: Yes i have checked but it doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried saving to a server file and then checking that as suggested in one of those comments? Have you tried using ob_end_clean() as I suggested as a workround in another?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in a text editor and looking for leading/trailing whitespace?

Comment: yes i have tried that also..

Comment: And? It feels like trying to drag blood from a stone trying to get the information needed to actually help you. What did you find when you opened the file in a text editor. Was there any leading or trailing whitespace? Was there a BOM header? Were there any obvious plaintext error messages? Was there any HTML markup?

Comment: NO there is no any Whitespaces

Comment: Then is it possible to upload a copy of the generated file somewhere so that I can investigate it?

Comment: Thank you for reply the problem has been solved thnx...

Comment: It's always good to explain how it was solved, for the benefit of others that might be having the same problem

Comment: The problem was: I have included the whole PHPExcel package in my Third party folder of Codeigniter instead of Classes that's why it does not fetch the methods.