# PHPExcel return a corrupted file

Tags: php, phpexcel

If I save it to file:

```
$objWriter->save("test.xls");
```

And then download from server, I can open file without any problems.

But when I try to save into `php://output`, got corrupted file like described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29131751/phpexcel-return-a-corrupted-binary-file) question.

I tried this:

```
ob_end_clean();
header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xls"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');

$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
```

`ob_end_clean();` doesn't help.

I tried `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007` and `PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5`. Same problem.

**UPD:** as I can see, excell file has BOM at start ("EF BB BF"). But I've checked all my script, they don't have BOM symbol. So, does it means that PXPExcell add BOM?

Comment: No, PHPExcel doesn't add any BOM: if it did, it would never work for anybody anywhere in the world (including myself)..... If a BOM Is being added it isn't by PHPExcel

Comment: @MarkBaker I don't have BOM symbols in my scripts. I've checked all files with hex editor, there is no `EF BB BF`

Comment: Is there anything else visible in the file when you view it in plaintext? Any leading/trailing whitespace? Any plaintext messages?

Comment: @MarkBaker if I open it as text, files started with `PK    ���GG�D�X  �     [Content_Types].xml��MN�0���"�%nY ��vAa`

Comment: Well it certainly shouldn't have a BOM header.... but are there any text messages visible in the file (not simply at the beginning)

Comment: @MarkBaker `xl/_rels/workbook.xml.rels­`, `docProps/app.xmlќSБ`, at the end of file: `xl/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.relsPK      С  М}`

Comment: @MarkBaker if I manually remove BOM symbols, I can open file normally.

Comment: I can't help identify where the BOM Is coming from, but none of the PHPExcel files contains a BOM header, in the same way they don't have no terminating `?>` tags to ensure that they can't inject anything untoward into the output stream

Comment: @MarkBaker my files neither doesn't have `?>`. So, any ideas how can I figure where is the problem?

Comment: Are you sure there are no characters (like spaces) before `<?php` tag?
If you have ending tag `?>` then remove it as well.

Comment: @TomaszTybulewicz I'm sure that I don't have spaces before `<?php`. But I use Zend Framework. Not sure about it =/

Comment: @Suvitruf I'm sure that Zend Framework is not to blame. The problem must lie in one of your files that are used. Could you upload one of the corrupted files to check?

Comment: @TomaszTybulewicz https://www.dropbox.com/s/nn25gwcqngdxmph/locals.xls?dl=0

Comment: @Suvitruf BOM need to exist in one of many files that are used to deliver the final page. It will be located before `<?php` tag in one of the files. That file had to be opened in poor editor like Notepad

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I added `ob_end_clean();` also after headers section. And BOM symbol disappeared.

```
ob_end_clean();
header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="test.xls"');
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: it worked. but its sad. i have another instance, with same set of code. excel can be export without problem. But another instance need to add these lines...  (i have already verified both of their php.ini are pretty much the same)

Answer (score 2):

User   **ob_end_clean(); **   Before u set the header

like this :

```
     ob_end_clean(); 
              header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel'); //mime type

            header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"filename.xls\"");
            header("Cache-Control: max-age=0");
            $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($object, 'Excel5');
              $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `ob_end_clean();` after  `$objWriter->save('php://output');` instead of header if the selected solution doesn't work for you

example:

```
    $filename = $name.".xls";
    ob_end_clean();
    header( "Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename='.$filename .' ');
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    header("Expires: 0");
    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    ob_end_clean();
```

Comment: IDK why this solution is downvoted as only after adding `ob_end_clean();` after `$objWriter->save('php://output');` worked for me and not after the header