# PHP Excel file format doesn't match extension

Tags: php, windows, phpexcel

I'm getting the above error (Windows only) on XLS files I'm exporting with my PHPExcel Script. Most of the reference I've seen to this error involves trailing/leading spaces/newlines when outputting to `php://output` ([PHPExcel generated excel file not working. (File format or extension is invalid )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16805851/phpexcel-generated-excel-file-not-working-file-format-or-extension-is-invalid). I'm not outputting in that fashion however. Instead I'm outputting the XLS file to a file path on my server and then passing a URL back to the browser to download. I've checked my PHP script and the file that it created for spaces and newlines at the beginning or end and there are none. Here's the section of my code that generates the PHP code.

```
$xls = new PHPExcel();
$xls->getActiveSheet()->setTitle(substr($reportName, 0, 31));
$xls->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
//iterate over the headers
foreach($headers as $i => $header){
    $xls->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue(getExcelColumn($i+1) . '1', $header);
}
//iterate over the table contents
foreach($tableContents as $rowNum => $row) {
    foreach($row as $col => $cell) {
        if(strpos($cell, "none specified") > -1)
            $cell = "N/A";
        $cell = explode("<br />", $cell);
        $cell = implode(", ", $cell);
        $xls->getActiveSheet()->SetCellValue(getExcelColumn($col+1) . ($rowNum+2), $cell);
    }
}
$fileName = createRandomKey(20) . '-' . $reportName . '.xls';
$w = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($xls);
$w->save("savedExports/$fileName");
```

`$headers` and `$tableContents` are taken from `$_POST` data and there's a few helper functions called in this code.

Comment: Watch out: strpos can return false, you should do `strpos($cell, "none specified") !== false`

Comment: Is the file on the server bad too, or just the downloaded file?

Comment: the variable $reportName is empty and you are using it in the line: $fileName = createRandomKey(20) . '-' . $reportName . '.xls'; Could you check what $reportName should be?

Comment: This is small portion of the code. `$reportName` is defined in another section of the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do:

```
$fileName = createRandomKey(20) . '-' . $reportName . '.xlsx';
```

`*.xlsx` is the right extension for Excel 2007 files

Also:

`strpos` can return `false`, you should do

```
strpos($cell, "none specified") !== false
```