# PHP - error reporting without closing tags

Tags: php, error-handling, tags

I'm trying to turn on error reporting in my code. My PHP version is 5.3.6.

I see error notice when I'm using following code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
sample_error
?>
```

even after comment line 2,

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

but when I remove closing tag, I can see only blank page.

I don't want to begin again [holy war about closing/not closing PHP tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag). I just want to know, what this has to error reporting, because for several months daily programming in PHP I didn't notice any similar difference when running script with/without it.

**EDIT**:
Now I noticed that when I put after my "sample_error" test line with echo

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
sample_error
echo 'test';
?>
```

again I can see only blank page. I'm confused...

**EDIT2**:
Notice which I mentioned:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant sample_error - assumed 'sample_error' in /home/hozanie/public_html/testy/error_report.php on line 5
```

Comment: do you have a space or other character before the opening tag?

Comment: technically that's not an error. It's an undefined constant that will be auto-converted to a string by PHP, and issue a Notice.

Comment: @Udan - no, I haven't, alike as after closing tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get a parse error without the `?>` at the end. This is because the way the php parser tries to correct the user's mistakes.

When there's a `?>` at the end the parser recognizes the last "line" with the undeclared constant (this is what `sample_error` looks like for the parser) and simply convert's it to the string `"sample_error"`. In php you can have string literals as statements and that's not a parse error, basically the closing `?>` act as a `;` as well. You should see something like this:

> Notice: Use of undefined constant sample_error - assumed
>   'sample_error'

Now without the closing `?>` the parser doesn't recognizes the end-of-file as "end of current statement" so your `sample_error` doesn't get to be auto-corrected to a string literal and you end up with a parse error. If you close the last statement with a `;` you get back to the previous error correcting behavior. On my system with php 5.4.17 it prints:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file

(i'm not sure if it's a mistake correction per se, I've seen a lot of php3 code with like `$array[somestuff]` and this could be some backward compatibility feature).