# Why is VS Code removing closing tag ?> on save. anyone knows?

Tags: php, tags

when i save my php file then VS Code removes ?> tag from ending. and its causing problems in execution.
I dont know why is this happening. If anyone knows please help.
Thank u.

**Update:** I was using Es-lint and Prettier extensions at the same time. I removed them and now its fine.

Comment: It's apparently good practice to remove it. PHPStorm even raises warnings if you have a closing tag in your PHP. I wouldn't be surprised if VS Code (or whatever plugin you're using) is removing it for style reasons. Are you absolutely sure it's the removal of your closing tag that's causing problems?

Comment: It is probably related to code style auto-formatting.  Check to see if it is set to use PSR-1, PSR-2 and/or PSR-12.  The reason it is considered good practice is that whitespace after this tag can be sent to the output buffer, causing issues with things like `header();`

Comment: There's no reason this should cause execution issues. Skipping it is actually recommended; it prevents an accidental space after it from breaking sites.

Comment: @Carcigenicate ur right i was using some extensions and those caused me some problems. btw extensions were es-lint and prettier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find two ways to solve this problem.

1. Go to VSCode settings and in the search bar type "format", then uncheck `Editor: Format on save`. Formatting the code will no longer work, but VSCode will also not delete the PHP closing tag.
2. Install the `php cs fixer` extension and I hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: 3. Accept it, as it's a best practice.

Answer (score 2):

End tag removal is covered here in detail: [PHP end tag "?>"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953483/php-end-tag)
It's recommended practice for pure PHP files.

Comment: ... which is why the linters remove them