# How to extract meta tags from multiple websites?

Tags: php, get-meta-tags

I am using this code to extract meta tags for one website but I am trying to get meta tags of multiple websites using a file.

```
<?php
$tags = get_meta_tags('https://demotiger.com');
$variable = $tags['description']; 
echo $variable;
?>
```

I tried to modify this code to get it to work for multiple websites:

```
<?php
$file = file_get_contents('website-list.txt');
$tags = get_meta_tags('$file');
$variable = $tags['description']; 
echo $variable;
?>
```

wesbite-list.txt

https://example.com
https://example2.com

Error I am getting:

> Warning: get_meta_tags($file): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\someserver\www\index.php on line 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Since your `wesbite-list.txt` contains multiple lines, so you need to extract this file contents as an array. For that use [file()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php)

2.After that iterate over  array and get the tags.

```
<?php

$websites = file('website-list.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
foreach($websites as $website){
    $tags = get_meta_tags($website);
    echo $tags['description'];
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Did you intend to end it with the curly bracket only, but no `?>`

Comment: @Ellie Kesselman `?>` is not required at all : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19953547/4248328

Comment: Only meta tags with name attributes will be parsed. Please suggest how to get all meta tags.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php (scroll down to notes)

Comment: @maqs please ask a new question regarding the same by providing proper input, code effort, current result, and expected outcome. You will get an answer for-sure. You can share your question link here for me to check as well.