# syntax error, unexpected end of file on Single.php file

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing, syntax

My single.php file has no error before I add this code :

```
<?php $orig_post = $post;
                global $post;
                $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                if ($tags) {
                $tag_ids = array();
                foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
                $args=array(
                'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
                'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                'posts_per_page'=>10, // Number of related posts that will be displayed.
                'caller_get_posts'=>1,
                'orderby'=>'rand' 
                );
                $my_query = new wp_query( $args );
                if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                echo '<div id="related_posts" class="clear"><h3>Related Posts</h3><ul>';
                while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                <li>
                     <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                     <?php the_post_thumbnail( 'related-posts' ); ?>
                     </a>
                     <div class="related_content">
                     <a href="<?php the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                     </div>
                </li>
                <?php
                };
echo '</ul></div>'; ?>
```

,piece of code to get **Related posts based on Category** inside single file which I found here :
http://www.webadvice.osvojito.com/wordpress-related-posts-without-plugin-with-thumbnails/

when I add this, I get this error : "syntax error, unexpected end of file"

I checked my code syntax several times, nothing's missing !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing 2 `}` on your code.

The last few lines of your code should be:

```
                <?php
                }
                }
                }
echo '</ul></div>';

?>
```

instead of:

```
                <?php
                };
echo '</ul></div>'; ?>
```

Comment: Oh my god. Very Amateur of me, I was blind not seeing them :| thank you so much

Comment: Easy to miss in wordpres templates.  Have a look at the code formatted in Sublime Text: http://pastebin.com/pAfMUmYp

Comment: you are missing a `?>` and the end of code :D btw, thanks for it

Comment: It's recommended to omit the close tag: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag

Comment: but I get error without it. Im using Zend Studio. it also gives error