# Using shortcode breaks RSS feed

Tags: php, wordpress, rss, shortcode

I had successfully created shortcode on my wordpress website to use it in the posts. But I later realised that it is breaking my rss-feed.

Here is the `shortcodes.php`

```
<?php
function disclaimer() {
    $disc = "&nbsp;<p style='font-style:italic;'> <strong>Disclaimer</strong> :</p>";
    return $disc;

}
add_shortcode('disclaimer', 'disclaimer');
?>
```

Here is how I am including it on the `functions.php`

```
<?php

include 'shortcodes.php';
```

So now, I am getting this error when I access my `rss` URL on my browser [image]

So when I removed this `include 'shortcodes.php';` my rss feed started working. But then I also want my shortcode to work. Am I doing anything wrong here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Works ok for me... try to remove the closing `?>` from shortcodes.php, it's not necessary and if there's any character after it [some things may break](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag)

Answer (score 0):

You can change your function so that the disclaimer is not added on feed page

```
function disclaimer() {
    if ( ! is_feed() ) {
        $disc = "&nbsp;<p style='font-style:italic;'> <strong>Disclaimer</strong> :</p>";
        return $disc;

    }
}
```

**Edit**:

Then it is not a problem with the code, but some problem with the file.

Make sure there is not extra space after the closing `?>` php tag. Or better, try to remove it completely.