# Paste Code function.php

Tags: wordpress, function

My function.php ends with this line:

```php
<?php } // this ends the admin page ?>
```

If I want to add any new code to my function.php, where should I paste it? Just BEFORE the closing tag `?>` or AFTER the closing tag.

I mean just before ?> In other words, just after the the word 'page'.

Comment: Before. But I have the vague feeling that you meant to ask "before or after the curly brace"?

Comment: Delete the `?>`, it's not necessary: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4410704/1287812

Comment: Just after the word "page" would be in the comment, now wouldn't it.

Answer (score 0):

delete this `?>` it is not necessary. 
Put your code in the very last line...

Comment: In summary, I can just delete "?>" or "// this ends the admin page ?>" and then add in the code.