# What is this empty text between tags?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have developed a PHP application and I am using ajax in it. I have a strange issue that when I use a code in another file it runs nice but when the code runs, some html tag is produced and in one location some empty string is generated. I don't know why this empty text is echo-ed between the tags.

url of pic: [picture of issue](http://www.axgig.com/images/37806704462167282398.png)

this is my code inside the ajax file:

```
<script language="javascript" src="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>js/app.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>css/grid.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>css/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>css/elements.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>css/forms.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>css/typographics.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $baseurl; ?>css/ie-fixes.css">
<?php //دریافت درخواست های کوئری استرینگ
if(!empty($_GET['mBLID'])) $mBLID = $_GET['mBLID'];
if(!empty($_GET['ctID'])) $ctID = $_GET['ctID'];
if(!empty($_GET['crID'])) $crID=$_GET['crID'];
if(!empty($_GET['loadingID'])) $loadingID = $_GET['loadingID'];
if(!empty($_GET['borderTitle'])) $borderTitle=$_GET['borderTitle'];
if(!empty($_GET['value'])) $receivedValue = $_GET['value'];
...?>
```

I totally go crazy for this problem because it creates an empty space between the input and makes it ugly

Comment: plz post complete hmtl code

Comment: i solve it. the problem cause for link tag. i most find a way to call css files by jquery or other ways

Comment: tanks @rack_nilesh but my code is very big

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not end a PHP file with `?>`. The following newline (as added by editors) is then "printed" to the client

Just remove the closing `?>`, and PHP will end processing the file automatically.

Also see here: [Why would one omit the close tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag)