# When to put "?>" at the end of php file?

Tags: php

Looking into code of few sites I noted that some php files have `?>` at the end of file and some doesn't. Doesn't it matter - and if it does, when must I put `?>` at the end of the file and when mustn't I?

Comment: It will make the compiler to understand the php coding has ended with ?>

Comment: Good practice not to close PHP tag.

Comment: Only when you want to explicitly exit PHP do you need one, if you don't have one and PHP hits the end of your page, it will terminate automatically.

Comment: good read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag

Comment: @Sumit I would argue the opposite. It's always a good practice to close your opening tags.

Comment: @TomaszCz. - I see too many cases of newlines or white space after a closing `?>` corrupting output.... common practise these days is to avoid using `?>` to prevent exactly that problem

Comment: @TomaszCz this is the issue and good to avoid headers already sent issues.

Comment: Thanks for clarification guys. I understand your point. Never thought of this that way.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Never use `?>` at the end of the file.

It's entirely optional but including it provides the opportunity to slip whitespace into the output by accident. If you do that in a file that you `include` or `require` before you try to output headers then you'll break your code.

Putting `?>` at the end of a PHP file has only drawbacks.

Answer (score 3):

Putting `?>` is optional if it is the last PHP tag. Omitting it in the last tag will benefit you in one case. There may be case where text editor append hidden special character after that tag. This could create problem. Omitting last closing tag will solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

From [PHP Official Documentation - Instruction separation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php)

> The closing tag of a PHP block at the end of a file is optional, and
>   in some cases omitting it is helpful when using [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php), so
>   unwanted whitespace will not occur at the end of files, and you will
>   still be able to add headers to the response later. It is also handy
>   if you use output buffering, and would not like to see added unwanted
>   whitespace at the end of the parts generated by the included files.