# PHP: /public_html/index.php NOT working, and Bluehost support has no idea why

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, php-5.4, bluehost

My problem is this: The website cannot access the index.php script file. It will not access it by default. It will not access it if I type it explicitly. I can, however, access the login.php script file which is contained in a different directory.
here is the contents of the .htaccess file

```
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
```

Here is the first 11 lines of the /public_html/index.php script file:

```
<?
session_start();
echo 'index start';
exit;
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'library/library.php';
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] === 'TRUE'){
//nothing....
}else{
$_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'FALSE'
}
```

The support personnel at bluehost said that there is an error on line 11 with a `}`. (forgive me, I forgot to copy the error exactly.)

I'm not a complete novice at PHP. I understand that the `exit;` on line 4 should prevent this error from happening. I am at a complete loss.

Comment: Its been ages since I have done any php but don't you need to close the script with ?>

Comment: Just a missing semi-colon in your else clause

Comment: no @paul, in fact people recommend not to use `?>`, and i still don't why. :)

Comment: Like I said before, nothing after line 4 should be executing, so if you aren't at least answering that problem, I can't honestly consider your critique of my code in lines 5-11 worth paying attention to as I try to solve this problem.

Comment: No @KyleBirch i'm sorry your understanding is incorrect. If there is a parse error even on line 2000000 and you have an exit on line 2 it wont work. Your have to fix the parse error first otherwise that `exit` as well as any other good code is meaningless.

Comment: @paul http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag

Comment: Thanks @tuananh - Told you its been ages

Comment: Thank you for that. Is there a way to prevent anything else from being parsed past a certain point?

Comment: @KyleBirch: You assume the exit prevents the rest of the code from being parsed, which is false. PHP *must* parse the whole file before executing the first line. You could use [`__halt_compiler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.halt-compiler.php) to achieve what you want. Godspeed.

Comment: I FINALLY understand my real problem. The local development environment I am used to had different settings with executing code when errors are found, and different settings for displaying parsing errors. It makes more sense now.

Thank you soo much everybody.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
session_start();
echo 'index start';
exit;
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'library/library.php';
if($_SESSION['logged_in'] === 'TRUE'){
  //nothing....
}else{
  $_SESSION['logged_in'] = 'FALSE';
}
```

Notice the `;` in `else` condition.

Comment: @jQuery.PHP.Magento.com i highly doubt it. we can skip the `{`&`}`, not the `;` in case of single line.