# Trailing newline in AJAX response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm doing an AJAX request and somehow a trailing newline is added somewhere.
My PHP script echoes (or is supposed to echo) `'SUCCESS'` if the request succeeded, `'ERROR'` otherwise.
But currently it returns: `'SUCCESS'` (i.e. `'SUCCESS\n'`).
I saw that by adding an `alert("!" + msg + "!")` that showed the line break.

My AJAX call:

```
function addMedia() {
    var addMediaName = $("#addMediaName").val();
    var notif;
    if(addMediaName != ""){
        $.ajax({
            url : '../../controler/add/addMedia.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : "mediaName="+ addMediaName,
            dataType : 'text',
            success: function(msg,data, settings){
                if(msg == 'SUCCESS'){
                    $.toaster({ priority : 'success', title : 'Success', message : 'Mode created' });
                } else {
                    $.toaster({ priority : 'warning', title : 'Failed', message : 'Mode already exists' });
                }
            },
        });
    }
}
```

My PHP controller:

```
<?php
include ('../../model/request/add.php');
if((include_once '../../model/request/add.php')===FALSE) exit('erreur include');
$mediaName = $_POST['mediaName'];
$mediaName = ucfirst(strtolower($mediaName));
$media = addMedia($mediaName);
?>
```

And the `addMedia` function:

```
function addMedia($mediaName)
{
    global $conn;
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    try {
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO media (mediaName) VALUES 
        ("'.$mediaName.'")';
        $conn->exec($sql);
        echo 'SUCCESS';
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERREUR';
    }
}
```

Any idea where that newline is coming from and how I can fix it?

Comment: add `die` after  echo 'SUCCESS'; die; or  echo 'ERREUR'; die;

Comment: damn it works... How ? I know that the line break is add after the echo 'SUCCESS' but i don't know where

Comment: if you don't die then code  execute next line of code or in this case it will call 'view' in MVC.

Comment: The thing is, I used the same code for adding others stuff and it works without `die` so I don't understand...

Comment: somewhere you code add extra space after function execution so better stop code execution when condition satisfy. :)

Comment: Indeed, I will let the `die` here but I'm curious to know why there is an extra space add ^^' By the way, thanks for your help

Comment: Anyway, if your `success` function is triggered, you know it's a success, right? Otherwise you should trigger an `error` function...

Comment: happy to help you :) . this is very common use of die; when use ajax call .

Comment: Wild guess: There's a newline after `?>`. If that's the case, just remove the `?>`.

Comment: I have an error function but I didn't show it because I know that the problem wasn't on it. The thing is I show a 2 different toaster : one when the media is created and one if it is already done. So I need the correct value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is most likely caused by the end of the PHP file, where a newline follows the `?>`.

Now while it is possible to `die`/`exit` at a previous point, I consider it a much cleaner solution to simply remove the `?>`.
The closing tag is not required by PHP, and it is usually even considered better practise not to use it, see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag).

Answer (score 2):

add [die()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_die.asp) or [exit()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_exit.asp) after

```
echo 'SUCCESS'; die;
```

or

```
echo 'ERREUR'; die;
```

if you can't add `die` then code execute next line of code or in this case it will call 'view' in MVC.

Comment: Or you can do easier by follow @Siguza answer : Wild guess: There's a newline after ?>. If that's the case, just remove the ?>

Comment: when you use ajax make sure to stop execution  by adding die() or exit() of code when you echo or print  rather then remove extra space or other code :)

Comment: "Rather write bad code and prevent its execution than writing good code." - No. Just no.

Comment: I get your point, however in that case, a new line after `?>` is not bad code, It's just a stupid and hard to find typo. I think the best thing to do is to die after you get the value you want, AND write good code :)

Comment: @Siguza  . when you use MVC . in you not stop code execution using `die()` or 'exit()'. it will call default layout or view file . in this case ?> formatting will not work .