# Facebook & html validation error: meta tags in body

Tags: php, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

this is not a duplicate,
I put meta tags in head element but facebook see it in body element,

btw: I'm using utf-8 without BOM
and I am obliged to, cause if I don't use it a PHP error will appear telling me HEADER already sent

this is facebook view of my code

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http%3A%2F%2Fanime-el3rab.com%2F

Comment: "*a PHP error will appear telling me HEADER already sent*" --> [Check this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag).

Comment: Your og:image url is wrong, and something else seems to be wrong with the structure of your HTML tags - check it in other validators to see if they're more specific about the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in my code,
there was a php include function,
that include function somehow generated a "paragraph tag"
the paragraph tag inside the head forced the head to be closed and the body to start, which made the rest of the elements that was writen after than include goes to body element