# why won't this page redirect?

Tags: php

I'm having a problem with redirecting a page in php.

```
<?php           
        include '../include/dbfunctions.php';
        $email = $password = "";
        $err = "";
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
            if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {

                $email = trim($_POST['email']);
                $password = trim($_POST['password']);

                $link = get_db_connection();


                if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
                    die(" Something went wrong ! ");
                }

                $user_email = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $email);
                $user_password = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $password);

                $query = "SELECT  username FROM user WHERE user_email = '$user_email' AND user_password = SHA1('$user_password') AND user_active = '1';";
                $data = mysqli_query($link, $query);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {

                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);

                    $username = $row['username'];
                    mysqli_close($link);
                    if (!empty($username)) {

                        header('location:http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.be/login/dashboard.php');
                        exit();
                    }
                } else {
                    $err = "Invalid combination of e-mail and password";
                    echo $err;
                }
            } else {

            }
        }
        ?>
```

I can't figure it out. If i fill in an invalid password or email, i get the error message. But when they are correct, nothing happens.

Comment: is it because you are using lowercase 'l' in location as it is `header('Location:...`. If no, what url you are getting in the browser ?

Comment: First check before header nothing is echo and use `Location:` like this.

Comment: Funny thing is that it works fine in Netbeans but no online???

Comment: the url doesn't change.

Comment: is it working with the uppercase 'L' in Location ?

Comment: Turn on error reporting at the top of your script - `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`. I suspect you have a "Headers already sent" error.. Also, the syntax is `header("Location: http://www.....");`. Could you also show your form html. You might not be processing anything..

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($username)) {
              header('location:http://www.xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.be/login/dashboard.php');
                    exit();}
```

`$username` might be empty.

Comment: that would mean that the query had no result? But it had.  i've checked this. 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1) {

Comment: Then remove the end php tag in dbfunctions.php, some times it will create problem.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag

Comment: i removed the end ?> tag but still no luck

Comment: The one of the reason might be why the redirect with header("Location: ...") is not working is, if your echoing something, before redirection.

Any header-redirection won´t work afterwards.

Comment: I don't echo before the redirect and even removed the echo in the else condition later. Still no winner.

Comment: Check it once in dbfunctions.php.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!empty($username)) {
     header('location:http://www.yoursite.be/login/dashboard.php?error=error in login please try agine');
     exit();
}
```