# Request a PHP script from Java and get the returned value?

Tags: java, php

so what I want to do is say I have a PHP file that does a check from `$_GET`, so basically something like this;

```
<?php
$test = $_GET['test'];
if ($test == "test") {
   return true;
}
else {
  return false;
}
?>
```

And that will be saved on my server as `test.php`, I want to send a request to `test.php` from my Java file, get the return and do a test on the return.

So something like this

```
Request(http://example.com/test.php?test=test)
if (Request Returned True) {
   Do
}
else {
   Do...
}
```

Any idea on how to do that? I'm still new to Java so excuse this please..

Comment: google for rest api

Comment: In php, you need to output something, such as json. In Java, you need to parse the result

Comment: @bub Okay, will do.

Comment: @Steve How do I send the request to the PHP file from Java though? And how do I parse the result it returns? I'm fine with returning Json

Answer (score 1):

In php  you need to echo some JSON:

```
<?php
$test = $_GET['test'];
if ($test == "test") {
   echo json_encode(['result'=>true]);
}
else {
    echo json_encode(['result'=>false]);
}
```

PS. Don't use `?>` [closing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag) at the end of php file.

In java you could get Apache [HttpClient](https://hc.apache.org/), [IOCommons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) (for IOUtils.toString) and [Org.JSON](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) (to parse JSON):

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet("http://example.com/test.php?test=test");

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getRequest);


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

JSONObject json = new JSONObject(IOUtils.toString(br));

json.getString("result"); //result
```

I haven't checked it, but hopefully, it should work.