# Closing PHP tags after exit or die functions

Tags: php

Should I close PHP tags after `die` or `exit` functions or it is not necessary?

Comment: I've read it before. It is not duplicate because of my different question about `die` and `exit` functions.

Comment: These particular language constructs make no difference.

Comment: @Luke It's an duplicate. Particular language constructs make no difference. The answer is the same.

Comment: Once you execute `exit()` or `die()`, the rest of the script is ignored. So the `?>` makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php), only omit the closing tag if it's at the end of the file:

> If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.

-- http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php

This applies to `exit` and `die` calls as well. They would run through the same parser as the rest of your php code.

Comment: Why not post this on the canonical duplicate target?

Comment: I posted my answer prior to seeing that a dup has been identified. Surprisingly, I don't see the official php docs quoted in any of the answers on that question, including the ones with hundreds of upvotes. I'll add my answer there too. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Careful about posting the same answer twice though, it raises an automatic moderator flag.

Comment: It's not exactly the same. This question is specific to `die` and `exit`. But I do quote the same quote from the docs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39084292/166339

Answer (score 1):

You'd still need to make sure your PHP is syntactically valid, even if the script might exit mid-point somewhere.

e.g. this will not work:

```
<?php
if (true) {
   die();
}
<html>
```

would not valid, because the PHP parser will barf on `<html>` - you're still in PHP mode, and `<html>` is not valid PHP code.

The script execution would never reach the tag, so theoretically it shouldn't matter that you don't have `?>`, but the parser doesn't check if something is logically reachable, it just checks the raw syntax.

Comment: I think the question is about closing the `<?php` tag with `?>`, not about closing HTML tags.