# Why autoload.php generated by composer not end with "?>"

Tags: php, composer-php

I am curious why autoload.php generated by composer not end with "?>" still works?

```
<?php
// autoload.php @generated by Composer
require_once __DIR__ . '/composer' . '/autoload_real.php';
return ComposerAutoloaderInit76c1d5886d625cc56dea5f7ed47e4565::getLoader();
```

Comment: because; if you had HTML below that, it would have (failed). It's also recommended not to close it off.

Comment: ^^ Yup, exact duplicate.

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag

Comment: Because it's beautiful! :)