# Blank spaces in php returning empty to ajax

Tags: php

I am comparing a string to check if a user already exist's , im doing it with ajax and i was sending an echo to compare it. and my comparison was always false and i was going crazy until i saw that BUG (don't know what to call that). Can someone explain me why this happens in php scripts?[image]

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use json_encode instead

Comment: i think i dont need that in this case , i just want to send a message if the username exists , if not i continue. but my question is : why blank spaces after or before "php scripts" send empty values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common practice in pure php scripts to omit closing tag, thats to avoid an infinite list of problems with invisible characters in the response.

Its even recommended in [the php manual](http://php.net/basic-syntax.phptags)

You can find more infos, some also related to ajax call/response, in this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag).

Comment: i cant , i dont have privileges yet.