# PHP: Maintain session data with a class object

Tags: php, session, object

I am a PHP OOP newbie and I am currently learning sessions. I have created a session class which is supposed to check if session variable `$_SESSION['userID']` is set, and set the login status to true; as well as set the user id.There is also a function, `setVars()` to set other object properties when called:
session.php

```
<?php 
class Session
{
public  $log_in_status=false;
public  $userID;
public  $fname;
public  $class_id;
public  $email;

public function __construct()
{
session_start();

if ($_SESSION['userID'])
{
    $this->log_in_status = true;
    $this->userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
}
else
{
    $this->log_in_status = false;
    unset($_SESSION['userID']);             
}
}


public function setVars($classID, $email, $fname)
{
$this->class_id = $classID;
$this->email    = $email;
$this->fname    = $fname;
}
}

$session = new Session();
```

The above class is in a require_once statement in init.php file:

```
<?php 
 #init.php
 require_once("session.php");
```

Page1.php sets some properties in the $session instance by calling the `setVars` method, and after echo them to the screen. However, page2.php is not able to echo these same values from the object properties:

```
<?php
# page1.php

  require_once("init.php");

  $class_id = 1;
  $email    = "test@test.com";
  $fname    = "Toto The Dog";

  $session->setVars($class_id, $email, $fname);


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing sessions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
        echo "Page 1 <br> <br>";
        echo "objectClassID: "   .$session->class_id . "<br>";
        echo "objectEmail  : "   . $session->email . "<br>";
        echo "objectFname  : "   . $session->fname . "<br> <br>";


        echo "<a href='page2.php'>Go to Page 2</a>";
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

//--------------------------------------------

```
<?php
# page2.php

 require_once("init.php"); 
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing sessions</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            echo "Page 2 <br> <br>";
            echo "objectClassID: "   . $session->class_id . "<br>";
            echo "objectEmail  : "   . $session->email . "<br>";
            echo "objectFname  : "   . $session->fname . "<br> <br>";

            echo "<a href='page1.php'>Go to Page 1</a>";
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I get page2.php to be able to display the `$session` object properties?

Comment: I highly recommend removing the closing PHP tag (ie `?>`) for any file where it's the last line. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag

Comment: As for your problem, you're never storing the *vars* in the session

Comment: There is no sign of OOP in your `Session` class. It is procedural programming disguised as OOP. Remove the `Session` class, it is useless, use `$_SESSION[]` directly and your code will be smaller, faster and easier to read an understand.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the *vars* across pages, you need to store them in the `$_SESSION` array. For example

```
<?php 
class Session {
  public $log_in_status = false;
  public $userID;
  public $fname;
  public $class_id;
  public $email;

  public function __construct() {
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['userID'])) {
        $this->log_in_status = true;
        $this->userID = $_SESSION['userID'];
    }

    $this->class_id = isset($_SESSION['class_id']) ? $_SESSION['class_id'] : null;
    $this->email = isset($_SESSION['email']) ? $_SESSION['email'] : null;
    $this->fname = isset($_SESSION['fname']) ? $_SESSION['fname'] : null;
  }

  public function setVars($classID, $email, $fname) {
    $this->class_id = $_SESSION['class_id'] = $classID;
    $this->email = $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
    $this->fname = $_SESSION['fname'] = $fname;
  }
}

$session = new Session();
```

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot

Comment: I would like to highlight the repeated and very appropriate use of `isset` in the answer above. This will help you prevent numerous warnings and runtime problems.