# json_encode passes null values

Tags: php, mysql, json

Code:

```
 <?php
$datoBuscar = $_GET["term"];

$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("ap_contable");

$ssql = "SELECT provincia_id, nombre, codigopostal FROM ciudades WHERE codigopostal LIKE '%" . $datoBuscar . "%' LIMIT 50";
$rs = mysql_query($ssql, $conexion);

$arrayElementos = array();

while ($fila = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){

     echo $fila[provincia_id];

     $queryp = "SELECT nombre FROM provincias WHERE id = '$fila[provincia_id]' LIMIT 1";
     $resultp = mysql_query($queryp, $conexion);
     $foundp = mysql_fetch_array($resultp);

     echo $foundp['nombre'];

     $row['prov'] = $foundp['nombre'];
     $row_set[] = $row;

}
echo json_encode($row_set);
?>
```

Example: http://localhost/Contable/autocompletecod.php?term=3269

The output of this is as follows

```
6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos6Entre Ríos[{"prov":null},{"prov":null},{"prov":null},{"prov": null},{"prov":null},{"prov":null},{"prov":null},{" prov":null},{"prov":null},{"prov":null},{"prov":nu ll},{"prov":null},{"prov":null},{"prov":null},{"pr ov":null},{"prov":null},{"prov":null}]
```

I put the ECHO intentionally to see if it is taking the data from the MySQL database and if it gets it. The problem is that when I assign it to the array $row['prov'] = $foundp['nombre']; Where is the problem? Where it says NULL should say Entre Rios

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user data is **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) and can be exploited.

Comment: I am not a professional programmer thanks for the advice

Comment: If you use PDO and placeholder values that will fix your string interpolation bug on your second query.

Answer (score 1):

Your strings need to be UTF-8 encoded (that's a `json_encode()` requirement). Try this:

```
$row['prov'] = utf8_encode($foundp['nombre']);
```

Alternatively, you can set the `CHARACTER SET` to `utf8mb4` in the MySQL connection. Ideally, you should have it all on UTF-8. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through).

Comment: Glad I could help. Don't forget to mark the question as resolved by accepting the answer that helped you most.

Comment: This?? <?php 
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>

Comment: It's okay like this Excuse my English, I'm from Argentina and I translate with google.<?php 
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'es_AR');
date_default_timezone_set('America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'); 
require("_config.inc.php");

$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
if(!$connection) {
 die("database connecction failed." . mysql_error());
}

$db_select = mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
if(!$db_select) {
 die("database selection failed." . mysql_error());
}
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
?>

Answer (score 0):

Uh, your code is just wrong for so many reasons:

1. mysql_* is deprecated
   http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php use PDO instead
2. Unprotected $datoBuscar variable passed to SQL
   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
3. Unused $arrayElementos
4. You should JOIN those two tables like: `SELECT p.nombre FROM provincias AS p JOIN ciudades AS c ON p.id = c.provincia_id WHERE c.codigopostal LIKE '%" . $datoBuscar . "%'` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html
5. $row_set is not defined
6. $row is not defined
7. ending ?> should NOT be used in pure PHP files [Why would one omit the close tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag)

So, it should look like this (untested code):

```
$datoBuscar = $_GET["term"];
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ap_contable', 'root', 'PASSWORD', [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"]);
$query = $db->prepare('SELECT p.nombre FROM provincias AS p JOIN ciudades AS c ON p.id = c.provincia_id WHERE c.codigopostal LIKE \'%?%\'');
$query->execute([$datoBuscar]);
$results = $query->fetchAll();
$json = [];
foreach($results AS $result)
{
   $row = [];
   $row['prov'] = $result['nombre'];
   $json[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json);
```

PS: If you want to write good PHP code, enable notice and warning error reporting, you will be amazed what you missed and "How this code worked in first place?!"

Answer (score 0):

To assign the $row array into $row_set array use this

```
$row_set = $row;
```

this way you will get everything of your $row array in $row_set.
And whenever you are running a loog and you are setting the value of $row_set at the same index then you will only get the last loop execution value in your array. If you want all the results then you can use `array_push();` 
description from php manual `int array_push ( array &$array , mixed $value1 [, mixed $... ] )`.
In your case you can use

```
array_push($row_set, $row);
```

Instead of

```
$row_set[] = $row;
```