# Codeigniter no connect in database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

My error >>>

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: ParseError
>
> Message: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file
>
> Filename: C:\wamp64\www\application\config\database.php
>
> Line Number: 97

---

```
   $active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'sistema', // your database name
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
?>
```

complete code https://pastebin.com/us3mycVT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the ?> at the end of that file.

Here you can find more information on why you shouldn't close the php tags on those files.

[Why would one omit the close tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410704/why-would-one-omit-the-close-tag)

Looked at the original file sent by the user. Basically there was a hidden character in the file. Created a new database.php with original encoding and everything worked fine.

Comment: I had already removed it before and nonetheless continued with the error

Comment: can you post the entire file?

Comment: Yes, but the site does not allow you to post a code with many lines

Comment: @PedroHB Link me to a pastebin with the entire file as a comment here

Comment: @PedroHB There's no problems with that code. Is the error still the same?

Comment: @PedroHB can you also link me the index.php file (first one on your app) and the application\views\errors\html\error_404.php file too?

Comment: Remove the first 8 lines of code from your 404 file. The 404 file shouldn't use the ci instance. You might need to workaround the use of that url helper there too.

Comment: @PedroHB tested your database.php file in a local ci install and it works fine. Must be something happening right after that file is loaded. Is there any way I can look into the project itself that's the only way I might be able to help here. Otherwise I think I'm out of options

Comment: do you have Facebook ?