# TesseractOCR PHP catching errors

Tags: php, ocr, tesseract

TesseractOCR PHP, how do I catch the error if the image returns no text?

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\UnsuccessfulCommandException: Error!

Comment: Same as you would with any other exception ...?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, it's all I need to catch the error:

```
<?php
require_once "vendor/autoload.php";

use thiagoalessio\TesseractOCR\TesseractOCR;

try{
    $parse = 
        (new TesseractOCR('path-to-image/blank.gif'))
        ->executable('C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tesseract.exe')
        ->run();
    echo $parse;
} catch(Exception $errors) {
    echo 'Message: ' .$errors->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: FYI it is usually a bad practice to close the php tags at the end of the file. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4499749/3992945 for more information about this

Comment: Sorry, it's just a habit, it really doesn't matter in my use case.