# Should I close my PHP tags?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   *[Why do some scripts omit the closing PHP tag, '?>'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219383)*

I've seen in a PHP framework (I can't remember which) that they didn't close the `php` tag (`?>`) at the bottom of the pages.

Why is that and should I do it too?

Comment: At least Laravel advises you to do that.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If it's a PHP file that contains **no** HTML, then don't close the tag.

This stops you from accidentally adding whitespace at the end of the file, therefore invoking browser output, and by extension headers, etc, which can cause a world of pain.

Answer (score 17):

The framework you saw is most probably [Zend Framework](http://framework.zend.com/). From the code style section of [their manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/coding-standard.php-file-formatting.html#coding-standard.php-file-formatting.general):

> For files that contain only PHP code,
>   the closing tag ("?>") is never
>   permitted. It is not required by PHP,
>   and omitting it´ prevents the
>   accidental injection of trailing white
>   space into the response.

Comment: The Yii framework also uses this style.

Answer (score 6):

Basically it means a PHP file won't have trailing whitespace.

If you include a file with trailing whitespace and try to set header() or cookies or stuff like that, then the trailing whitespace will cause a problem.

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer not to do it as it caused some unexpected troubles in the past. If you have white space(s) after closing tag, it **might** cause some troubles (like outputting this white space to browser, which is unpleasant if you are parsing XMLs) which are quite hard to debug.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to, as long as it's also the end of that script.

Adding `?>` to the end of a file doesn't serve any purpose, it just adds a few bytes to the filesize.