# Export to csv with BOM, Strange space begining of document that makes trouble

Tags: php, csv, utf-8, export, byte-order-mark

In order to get excel to read csv document properly without converting it to ASCII characters you need to have a UTF-8 BOM (3 bytes, hex EF BB BF) at the start of the file.

this is the function I use to export to csv

```
    function download_csv_results($results, $name)
    {   
        header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8");
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='. $name);
        header('Pragma: no-cache');
        header("Expires: 0");
        $outstream = fopen("php://output", "w");
fwrite($outstream, "\xEF\xBB\xBF");
         fputcsv($outstream, array_keys($results[0]));



        foreach($results as $result)
        {
            fputcsv($outstream, $result);
        }

        fclose($outstream);
    }
```

The issue is when i view it in hex I see

```
20 ef bb bf
```

as opposed to

```
ef bb bf 20
```

I think 20 is a space but what causes that space, and why it's at the beginning of document is what I can't figure out.

Comment: Try adding a fourth byte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40448424/4535386)  I figured it out i had a space at the begining of the file `" <?php"` for some reason it was included in the document I would appreciate if someone could explain to me why it was included.