# Include an IF and his corresponding else in PHP

Tags: php, if-statement, include

Hi guys I'm trying to do a strange thing, I want put all of my code, of all my website pages inside an if, for example I want do this:

```
<?php
    include('..../...../php/secure-open.php');
    if(......){
     ALL OF WEBSITE CODE HERE
    include('..../...../php/secure-close.php');
 }
```

Where secure-open.php is:

```
<?php
    if(security check here){  
?>
```

And secure-close.php is

```
<?php 
    }else{
    die();
    }
?>
```

So all the will will be executed only if the security condition is true, but when I try to do it, it says, Unexpected document ends on line`....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I close my PHP tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5701747/should-i-close-my-php-tags)

Comment: You have to close an opening `{` in the same PHP file by a `}`. What you want is certainly possible, but not in this way. Use a function like `function passedAllSecurityChecks() { ....<checks> ....}` in `secure-open.php` and let it return a boolean. You then use that function in your main PHP file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have missed closing bracket :)

You really should not resolve your security checks that way, but if you really sure that's what you need, move "ALL OF WEBSITE CODE" to different file and just include it inside that if.

```
if(security_check) {
    include "website.php";
} else {
    die();
}
```

And one more easy-to-implement fast check:

index.php:

```
if (security_check) {
    define('SECURE', true);
}
require "website.php";
```

website.php:

```
if (!defined('SECURE')) {
   die();
}
```