# How to detect the current template being displayed in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a child theme of Twenty Eleven theme. There I need some customization in the blog page. I want to add a class in the place of `id = "primary"`. How to discover which template is rendering the page?

Comment: Hi, try the index.php file. It puts together the home page when no home.php file exists.

Comment: [This article](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) is a pretty good explanation what theme file is used for what purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code in your child theme's `functions.php`.
If you don't have it, create an empty one and use only the [php opening tag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3219383/1287812) (`<?php`).

This will print in `the_content` the current theme and template being displayed.

#### Seeing the main site page: child theme **have** an `index.php`

> [image: child theme index.php]

#### Seeing a single post: child theme **don't have** a `single.php`

> [image: parent theme single.php]

Using a filter to add debugging to the content: check the comments

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'so_13737534_print_template', 20 );

function so_13737534_print_template( $content ) 
{
    // $template value equals to:
    // /public_html/wp-content/themes/theme-name/template-name.php
    global $template;

    // Return normal content if seeing the backend 
    // or the user is not administrator
    if( is_admin() || !current_user_can( 'delete_plugins' ) )
        return $content;

    // Split the value and build the output html
    $split_path = explode( '/', $template );
    $total = count( $split_path ) - 1;
    $theme_and_template = $split_path[$total-1] . '/' . $split_path[$total];
    $print = '<strong style="font-size:1em;background-color:#FFFDBC;padding:8px">Current = ' . $theme_and_template . '</strong>';

    // Add our output before the_content
    $content = $print . $content;
    return $content;
}
```

---

#### The same can be printed as an Html comment in the `<head>`, using:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'so_13737534_print_template_in_head', 999 );

function so_13737534_print_template_in_head() 
{
    global $template;
    echo '
    <!--

    TEMPLATE = ' . $template . '

    -->
    ';
}
```