# PHP file_get_contents() and file_put_contents from csv

Tags: php, image, csv, file-get-contents

I'm trying to write a script that will allow for a two column .csv file (1st column with names, 2nd with image urls) to be read, and the images to then be saved to my hard drive using the first column as the saved file name. I'm able to get some images to save (all the files are created, but some are missing data). The naming convention works the way I want it to, but I need to get all of the files. Anyone care to take a look? Might be worth mentioning that I'm using MAMP but the image addresses in the .csv are all valid (I echoed out the image address with  tags, so I know they work).

```
<?php
    //header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    //header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename ='
    //Eli's 2 column CSV grab-n-save file

    $file = 'Random.csv'; //put file path of .csv here
    $buffer = file_get_contents($file);
    //print_r($buffer);
    $pattern = '/[,\n]/';

    $catch = preg_split($pattern, $buffer);
    $keep_track = 0;

    foreach($catch as $value)
    {
        if ($keep_track%2 == 0)
        {
        //if first column is sku
            $name = $value;
            $keep_track += 1;
        }
        elseif ($keep_track %2 == 1)
        {
            //if an image
            $name = str_replace(' ', '',$name);

            //Change pathname to MAMP specs
            $name2 =  '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/picturegrab' . $name . '.jpg';

            file_put_contents($name2, file_get_contents($value), FILE_APPEND);
            //echo $value . '<br/>';
            $keep_track += 1;

            echo $name2 . '<br/>' . '<img src='.$value.'><br/>';
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: what is your question ?

Comment: can you add sample csv and your expected output ?

Comment: maybe read string by string with [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) is better

Comment: My question is, how come some of the images are saving as the images they should be, yet others have zero bytes of data? It's completely random. My sample csv looks like this

    ------------------------------------------------------------
      Name                   |      Webaddress
      Jon Smith                 http://somewebsite.com/image.jpg
      Patty Jones               http://somewebsite.com/image.jpg
    -------------------------------------------------------------

The files save on my computer as jonsmith.jpg & patty.jpg, but even though images display, they aren't saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

some logic

```
$file = fopen('Random.csv');
$dir = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/picturegrab/';
while (list($name, $img_link) = fgetcsv($file)) {
  $name = str_replace(" ", "", $name);
  copy($img_link, $dir.$name.'.jpg');
}
```

updated my example to make it more responsive

also thx to **Sam Green** with his coment

Comment: I'm no longer seeing anything. This is probably because it's not echoing, but the files aren't saved either.

Comment: Nevermind - this worked beautifully once I used $file = fopen('Random.csv'); Tanks a ton!

Comment: oh, sorry, I forgot that [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.fgetcsv.php) needs a resource of opened file, not the file +1

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove the whitespace before the opening php tab or else you will get junk whitespace and a `headers already sent` error will show up in the csv when you download it
2. Remove the closing php tag as it is not necessary and will also help to prevent garbage whitespace [Why do some scripts omit the closing PHP tag, '?>'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219383/why-do-some-scripts-omit-the-closing-php-tag)
3. Use fgetcsv (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to get the data
4. Use fputcsv (http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to write the data

Comment: White space is removed, I haven't taken out the ?> though. I will try modifying the code shortly - thanks for the input!