# how can I get barcode lines instead of these weird characters?

Tags: zend-framework

I am running this function and I am getting this. How can I get the awesome looking barcode instead?

```
    public function barAction()
{

    $barcodeOptions = array('text'=>'Test');
    $rendererOptions = array();

    Zend_Barcode::factory('code39','image',$barcodeOptions,$rendererOptions)->render();

}
```

�PNG  IHDR�(*3;7vIDATx����r� �a���*�^8�PX6��:�w�i�1x�TM9� "����"��A`��� @�0,a�V�SJUIι*ܯ55�rIb�ʅ�pk"�,�*K�RJmD���S�#��,���pw$H� K/�#\�������!��a� >jK����y}��<�����[��i.�qu��~�e����j�RV��0�ȳ%#d�!��1�^=��|��YX~S3�����Z��j�^���u�:�է���z�Y�Kʒ�ѻ4�q 4i����[s�0���3����Y���'����\��m�1����:X��0��O�;��-�ٺ �|?�ӻ����� 1�pޚ밎=���7L�}�LC������(Ye�V�kH/l��ʏ��{   �×8�Z�O��n̓�?s�u.������+�w4Tg�r��U����U{��ԛDs����K~��J�� n�� @�0,aX� ��A`�}��3|�6�IEND�B`�

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are probably sending a `Content-Type` header other than `image/png` for your response. Zend_Barcode will send `Content-Type: image/png` by default when you call the `render()` method, so what you are seeing could mean one of a couple things.

1. You could be issuing a non-image header (for example: `header("Content-Type: text/html');`) before your call to barAction()
2. Because headers need to be sent before any content, you could be unknowingly printing out some output somewhere in the dispatch process before barAction. This could be as simple as a line or space before a `<?php` tag in one of your Controllers (or other non-view PHP classes).  As a first step, check your controller that houses barAction and make sure that the very first line is `<?php` and that [there is no closing `?>` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219383/why-do-some-scripts-omit-the-closing-php-tag). You may need to investigate plugins or other included files as well.

Comment: it is working only if I am calling that Action method in another method and placing the url in the img tag.