# headers already - Puzzling version - . Works locally, not live

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am aware that there should be no whitespace before the php code. However my code gives me the following error on the **live** server, but **not** on my **test** Apache server:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mydomain/public_html/parts/includes/dbinfo.inc.php:5) in /home/mydomain/public_html/parts/update_part.php on line 55

I have tried removing the `functions.inc.php`still getting the same problem.
 Below are the 2 pieces of code involved:
a) dbinfo.inc.php

```
    <?php
$username="myusername";
$password="mypassword";
$database="mydatabase";
?>
```

b) update_part.php

```
<?php

include("./includes/dbinfo.inc.php");
include("./includes/functions.inc.php");

mysql_connect("localhost","$username","$password") or die("Error: ".mysqlerror());
mysql_select_db("$database"); 

//get the variables we transmitted from the form
        $part_id            = $_POST['part_id'];
        $part_manufacturer      = $_POST['part_manufacturer'];
        $part_descr             = $_POST['part_descr'];
        $part_price         = $_POST['part_price'];
        $part_code          = $_POST['part_code'];
        $part_status            = $_POST['part_status'];
        $part_image             = $_POST['part_image'];
        $part_cat           = $_POST['part_cat'];
        $ave_mth_usage          = $_POST['ave_mth_usage'];
        $reorder_level          = $_POST['reorder_level'];
        $reorder_qty            = $_POST['reorder_qty'];
        $other_item_details             = $_POST['other_item_details'];
        $part_stock_taking_date         = $_POST['part_stock_taking_date'];
        $part_qty_in_stock      = $_POST['part_qty_in_stock'];


        $part_manufacturer      = mysql_real_escape_string($part_manufacturer);
        $part_descr             = mysql_real_escape_string($part_descr);
        $part_code          = mysql_real_escape_string($part_code);
        $part_status            = mysql_real_escape_string($part_status);
        $part_cat           = mysql_real_escape_string($part_cat);
        $other_item_details             = mysql_real_escape_string($other_item_details);


//replace TestTable with the name of your table
$sql = 
    "UPDATE part SET 
        part_manufacturer       = '$part_manufacturer',
        part_descr          = '$part_descr',
        part_price          = '$part_price',
        part_code           = '$part_code',
        part_status             = '$part_status',
        part_image          = '$part_image',
        part_cat            = '$part_cat',
        ave_mth_usage           = '$ave_mth_usage',
        reorder_level           = '$reorder_level',
        reorder_qty             = '$reorder_qty',
        other_item_details      = '$other_item_details',
        part_stock_taking_date          = '$part_stock_taking_date',
        part_qty_in_stock       = '$part_qty_in_stock'


    WHERE part_id = $part_id";
//mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
do_query($sql,__LINE__);
header("Location: ./view_parts.php");
?>
```

The offending code at line 55 is the line just before the final line of b) i.e.

```
header("Location: ./view_parts.php");
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Seems your `dbinfo.inc.php` has whitespace before the `<?php` ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php/12770075#12770075 . Remove the ending `?>` tags. Also, if you're transferring files to the live server via FTP, make sure to use Binary mode rather than Text.

Comment: @niloct sorry, that's just a result of copying in to query. It isn't actually there

Comment: @Dcoder I didn't realize that ?> tags were not necessary! Since when and why?

Comment: dont output anything before using header() in your script, may be you have some output in dbinfo.inc.php, make it sure

Comment: @Dk-Macadamia the code for dbinfo.inc.php is shown in a) above and is just setting up login variables.

Comment: @Geoff: [The `?>` tag is only necessary if it is followed by something you *want* to output](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php). In practice, using this tag at the end of a file is just asking for trouble - your question is a perfect example of what happens when whitespace gets added to the end of your file either by your IDE (e.g. a setting like "add blank lines to the end of source files"), your FTP client transferring in Text mode and messing up newlines, or other factors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should delete php closing tag from your php script and all spaces before opening tag and all this again in the included php scripts

Comment: That worked. Thanks also to @Dcoder for mentioning it, and to all you guys with helpful suggestions.

Comment: still I would like to know why the closing tags are now unecessary, as  I have always used them. Ok I looked it up at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219383/why-do-some-scripts-omit-the-closing-php-tag)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4410704/3444240

Answer (score 2):

Check file encoding - use UTF-8 **without BOM**.
You can use output buffering.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are having an error or warning output to the page.  Check the source of the page.

For the 'header' command to work, there must be no prior output.

Output buffering may help if you use  ob_clean() .  You can also turn off displaying errors in your php.ini file.

Comment: As a note to the ACCEPTED solution above, the closing tags have never been necessary, in fact, you don't even need to use `<?php` as the opener, you could use a shortcut `<?` instead.  The whitespace is where the problem lies, not in the fact that you had a closing tag (unless you had whitespace after the closing tag.  More or less, this is a lazy way of coding -- to not put the closing tag -- akin to not using `{` `}` on if/while/etc statements. Personally, i find these directives make the code easier to follow where stuff starts and ends... but people are lazy so what can I say.

Answer (score 0):

This might cause an error: remove the spaces before any

```
<?php
```

opening tags.