# Is that syntactically correct to omit closing tag in a PHP file?

Tags: php, syntax

I often see PHP files where the closing php tag `?>` is omitted.
Why is this permitted by the language and what are the benefits (if any) ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3219383/1135424

Comment: Have you looked at the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php `If a file is pure PHP code, it is preferable to omit the PHP closing tag at the end of the file. This prevents accidental whitespace or new lines being added after the PHP closing tag, which may cause unwanted effects because PHP will start output buffering when there is no intention from the programmer to send any output at that point in the script.`

Comment: Honestly, I didn't see this section. That'd be the answer of my question. Thanks !